# C programming exercise about functions and addresses

Tags: c

Alright, so very,very newbie to prgramming here and I'm working through the last 2 weeks of my C programming class which is a struggle. So far I have managed to scrape by. I'm working with Chapter 9 of the C Primer Plus book, and this week I have this problem.

"Write and test a function that takes the addresses of three double variables as arguments and that makes the value of the smallest variable into the first variable, the middle value into the second variable, and the largest into the third variable."

Can anyone explain what exactly this is asking of me? I have read the chapter numerous times and I am just not getting it. All I end up with is sheer confusion.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First things first. You need to show some effort on this. Please look at the basics on C programming: functions, variables, addresses (pointers use) etc. Use every keyword as a search term, and when you get the concepts, you will be able to do it easily.

Comment: It asks you to write a "call by reference" function like this: `void dostuff(double * first, double * second, double * third)` and swap the values in `first`, `second` and `third` accordingly. The `*` will not contain the double value, but the adress to it, so you can change the values of the doubles.

Comment: I can't suppose that a teacher asks you to do that kind of function without any course/examples on what pointers are and their usage for 'passing by reference' (well, it is not reference, I know).

Comment: @hexasoft: I used the term "call by reference", too in this case. I think its OK to call it that way in this case.

Comment: @Nidhoegger: well yes. But sometimes when people comes to C from a language with references it may lead to confusion, so I prefer be prudent :)

Comment: @Nidhoegger No it's not. It will just make things confusing when the OP gets to C++. The term is "pass by address."

Comment: @CareyGregory, technically its still call by value. But instead of copying the variables content, you copy its adress. You still wont be able to alter the content of the passed variable, e.g. altering the adress of the passed variables.

Comment: @hexasoft, yeah, you are right. Didnt think of that case

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I better get to work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what exactly this is asking of me?

Here's a restatement of the problem:

Given three `double` variables with the values

```
a = 10.0;
b = 15.0;
c = 8.0;
```

write a function `func` that takes pointers to these variables

```
func( &a, &b, &c );
```

such that after the function returns, the values in `a`, `b`, and `c` are

```
a == 8.0;
b == 10.0;
c == 15.0;
```

Comment: Thanks John, makes sense now. Much appreciated, I guess I've just been reading it differently.

Comment: @Allen: It definitely could have been worded a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> Write and test a function that takes the addresses of three double variables as arguments and that makes the value of the smallest variable into the first variable, the middle value into the second variable, and the largest into the third variable.

Most useful way to restate the homework is to write a test harness that takes a function you wrote and verifies whether it works correctly.

This test harness is a blank slate where you need to add the implementation of your function. The asserts will trigger whenever your function performs incorrectly. The meaning of an `assert` statement is: we assert that what's given as the parameter is true, otherwise it's a failure and the program should terminate.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// The defintion of the function that takes there addresses of doubles.
// You need to implement it - so far it does nothing and leaves the numbers
// as they were.
void fun(double * a, double * b, double * c)
{
  // TODO
}

// The test helper. Returns true (1) on when fun acted correctly on the
// given parameters, false (0) on failure (otherwise).
int test(double a, double b, double c) {
  double a0 = a, b0 = b, c0 = c; // original values
  assert(a==a0 && b==b0 && c==c0); // make sure that comparisons work as we expect
  fun(&a, &b, &c);
  return 
    // postcondition from the homework: first variable must be now smallest,
    // second variable must be middle, third variable must be largest
    a <= b && b <= c
    // additionally, the output must be a permutation of the inputs -
    // otherwise a fun body of { *a=0; *b=0; *c=0; } would "pass"
    && (
         (a==a0 && b==b0 && c==c0)
      || (a==a0 && b==c0 && c==b0)
      || (a==b0 && b==a0 && c==c0)
      || (a==b0 && b==c0 && c==a0)
      || (a==c0 && b==a0 && c==b0)
      || (a==c0 && b==b0 && c==a0)
    );
}

int main()
{
  // test on positive numbers
  assert(test(0.0, 1.0, 2.0));
  assert(test(0.0, 2.0, 1.0));
  assert(test(1.0, 0.0, 2.0));
  assert(test(1.0, 2.0, 0.0));
  assert(test(2.0, 0.0, 1.0));
  assert(test(2.0, 1.0, 0.0));
  // test on mixed positive/negative
  assert(test(-1.0,  0.0,  1.0));
  assert(test(-1.0,  1.0,  0.0));
  assert(test( 1.0,  0.0, -1.0));
  assert(test( 1.0, -1.0,  0.0));
  assert(test( 0.0,  1.0, -1.0));
  assert(test( 0.0, -1.0,  1.0));
  // test on negative numbers
  assert(test(-2.0, -1.0,  0.0));
  assert(test(-2.0,  0.0, -1.0));
  assert(test(-1.0, -2.0,  0.0));
  assert(test(-1.0,  0.0, -2.0));
  assert(test( 0.0, -1.0, -2.0));
  assert(test( 0.0, -2.0, -1.0));
  // test with repeated numbers
  assert(test(1.0, 1.0, 2.0));
  assert(test(1.0, 2.0, 1.0));
  assert(test(2.0, 1.0, 1.0));
  assert(test(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
  // If we've ran up to here, the implementation of fun is likely
  // to work correctly.
  printf("Hurray! fun is likely to be correct.\n");
}
```